# Create Smart Contract and use ABI functions

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

For a recent test it's been requested me to generate a Smart Contract with Ethernum and use some functions provided through ABI json to extract some info.
I'm using https://ropsten.etherscan.io as suggested.

I studied Ethernum for the last 2 days and I tried with Solidity Remix to extract these info but I don't understand how to use the ABI functions with Solidity Remix.

All I have is an Address contract and an ABI contract. 
Is there someone available to provide me some info?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to programmatically do it using a library like **[web3js](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API)**, web3js allows you to interact with the Ethereum network (accounts, smart contracts) through the RPC webservice.

In the following example, I deployed a contract called **SimpleStorage** on a local blockchain with [Truffle](https://truffleframework.com/ganache) and [Ganache](https://truffleframework.com/ganache) (tools and framework for ethereum).

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

contract SimpleStorage {
    uint public value;

    function SimpleStorage() {
        value = 1;
    }

    function setValue(uint val) {
        value = val;
    }

    function getValue() returns(uint) {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Each contract deployed on the Ethereum Blockchain has a ABI (*Application Binary Interface*) sort of Swagger for your Smart Contract. Programs use the ABI to interact with the Smart Contract via RPC.

Each contract is deployed at a unique address like `0x3450226a2fccb0d3668e7c3a730c43ef50ec8a06`

**1. Initiate a nodeJS project and add web3js library**

```
$ npm init
$ npm install web3@0.20.6 -s
```

**2. Create a JavaScrit file `index.js`**

Inject the dependency

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
```

Declare the rpc endpoint of your node. I'm using a local blockchain, but you could easily connect to a Ropsten public node with [Infura](https://infura.io/) for example (depends on which network you contract is deployed)

```
const RPC_ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:8545" //https://ropsten.infura.io
```

Connect to a Ethereum node

```
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(RPC_ENDPOINT));
```

Set default account

```
web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0]
```

Put your ABI here and the address where the smart contract is deployed

```
var abi = [...];
var address = "0x3450226a2fccb0d3668e7c3a730c43ef50ec8a06";
```

Load the contract schema from the abi

```
var SimpleStorageContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);
```

Instantiate the contract by address

```
var simpleStorageContractInstance = SimpleStorageContract.at(address);
```

Call one of the ABI function

```
var value = simpleStorageContractInstance.getValue.call();
console.log("value="+value);
```

**Result:**

When I invoke the function `getValue` of my SimpleStorage contract instance, the function returns 1.

```
value=1
```

**Full code:**

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const RPC_ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:8545"

// Connection to a Ethereum node
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(RPC_ENDPOINT));

// Set default account
web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0]

// ABI describes a smart contract interface developped in Solidity
var abi = [
    {
      "constant": true,
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "value",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "",
          "type": "uint256"
        }
      ],
      "payable": false,
      "stateMutability": "view",
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "inputs": [],
      "payable": false,
      "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
      "type": "constructor"
    },
    {
      "constant": false,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "val",
          "type": "uint256"
        }
      ],
      "name": "setValue",
      "outputs": [],
      "payable": false,
      "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "constant": false,
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "getValue",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "",
          "type": "uint256"
        }
      ],
      "payable": false,
      "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
      "type": "function"
    }
  ];

// Address where the smart contract is deployed
var address = "0x3450226a2fccb0d3668e7c3a730c43ef50ec8a06";

// Load the contract schema from the abi
var SimpleStorageContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);

// Instanciate by address
var simpleStorageContractInstance = SimpleStorageContract.at(address);

// Call one of the ABI function
var value = simpleStorageContractInstance.getValue.call();
console.log("value="+value);
```

**GitHub of the project:**

https://github.com/gjeanmart/stackexchange/tree/master/51809356-create-smart-contract-and-use-abi-functions

**Ethereum StackExchange**

There is a dedicated StackExchange community for Ethereum questions [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thank you very much Greg, it looks like the contract is deployed on Ropsten. I created the file as you suggested but I'm having problem when I set the address `Error: invalid address` I don't know if there is some relation with the RPC

Comment: Have you done this part: `web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0]`

Comment: Yes, sorry, the problem is with one of the ABI function who is looking for a Bytes32 value, It's basically a Kemmak.

Comment: @MirkoUrru did you manage to find the problem related to invalid address? Im having the same issue... i get web3.isconnected() == true.. but when i call a function i get invalid address. The input of the function is "bytes32".. do i need to convert it into an array?